# Is it possible to create a new type of loop in C#?

Tags: c#, loops

This question is more out of curiosity than practical need (so you don't have to suggest other ways of accomplishing these examples), but I'm wondering: is it possible to create a new type of loop in C#?

A few examples I can think of:

```
repeat(5) {
    // This will repeat 5 times, equivalent to "for(int i=0; i<5; i++)"
} 

foreachBackwards(GameObject entry in list) {
    // This is like a foreach loop, but it goes in reverse
}

maxwhile(Method() == false; 100) {
    // This will act like a normal While loop, but will auto-break after 100 attempts
}
```

I know you can do all these things by adding internal logic to existing for/while loop types, but I'm just wondering, is this sort of thing possible? Or are the pre-built loops the only types you can use?

Comment: Yes, using Roslyn extensions you can extend C# any way you want - but it's a **lot** of work (needing to define syntax, semantics, flow analysis, compatibility with existing static analysis toosl, etc), though you can even get VS to recognize your new syntax too. But overall: introducing new syntax when there's perfectly-fine built-ins is just asking for trouble - and consider your successor who will have to maintain the project after you leave.

Comment: Ugh, just 12 minutes later and I've already got two downvotes, losing me 4 reputation just for posting a clear and concise code-focused question with examples. Now I remember why I don't use StackOverflow anymore! I imagine it will be closed as a duplicate of an unrelated question within the hour. Thank you @Dai for actually answering the question. Feel free to post it as an answer and I'll accept it. And I totally get that it's not a good idea, like I said, I was just curious if it was possible since I'd never seen anyone do it before.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me that all of these are possible with LINQ.

```
foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 5))
{
    // This will repeat 5 times, equivalent to "for(int i=0; i<5; i++)"
}

foreach (GameObject entry in list.AsEnumerable().Reverse())
{
    // This is like a foreach loop, but it goes in reverse
}

foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 100).TakeWhile(x => Method() == false))
{
    // This will act like a normal While loop, but will auto-break after 100 attempts
}
```

NB: the `.AsEnumerable()` is needed if `list` is a `List<GameObject>`, but otherwise it's not needed.

LINQ will let you create, by composition, all sorts of loop variants.

Comment: As I said, I'm not looking for other ways to do this, I know how to replicate this kind of functionality in general. I was asking if it was possible to create new types of loops, specifically, as a way to increase my own knowledge of programming.

Comment: Sorry, this is answering the question of new types of loops. Are you expecting that there is hidden syntax for creating loops? How were you expecting your question to be answered other than something like my answer?

Comment: I was expecting either "yes it's possible, here's how" or "no it isn't possible." Something can be unknown to me personally without being "hidden syntax." Your answer describes how to use foreach loops to do many things, but I was asking if it was possible to NOT use foreach loops at all, but define a new type of loop entirely, the same way we can define entirely new structs and classes.

Comment: @Nerrolken - Would `Enumerable.Range(0, 5).ForEach(i => ...);` be something more like what you're looking for?

Comment: I think maybe I need to clarify: this isn't a functionality question, this is a syntax question. I was literally asking "can I make something like repeat(5) { }". I know how to achieve that functionality any number of other ways, including the ways you suggested. I was asking if it's possible to literally write "repeat(5) { }" and have it work. To define an entirely new loop type, not to use for/foreach/while to achieve those same ends, which I can already do. I wasn't looking for help on how to DO something, I was just curious if it was possible to WRITE something.

Comment: Again, it was idle curiosity, not a question of trying to make something work practically. I was trying to learn and grow as a programmer, to investigate something I'd never tried before. Dai's comment of "yes but it's a huge pain" was entirely satisfactory. Your suggestions, while being perfectly fine examples of how to achieve the FUNCTIONALITY I described, all involve using "foreach" loops. The point of my question was "can I make something new, rather than using for, foreach, and while?" Therefore suggestions which use "foreach" are missing the point.

Comment: @Nerrolken - Then Dai's suggestion in the comments is probably the way to go. You can code up anything with Roslyn, but you'd end up making non-standard C#.